# jquery select part of the total json output

Tags: jquery, json

My [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppeer/6gDMX/) produces the json object in a string:

How can I just select the html part? Any help would be appreciated. Regards Peer.
It's this piece of code which needs adjustment;

```
  var json_text = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
  alert(json_text);
```

Comment: Simply use `data.query.results.json.html`

Comment: by simply using the json encoded data object...thanks a lot!

Comment: Did it worked for you?

Comment: Satpal...spot on it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

```
var html = data.query.results.json.html;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6gDMX/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
console.log(data.query.results.json.html);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/anubhavranjan/8bnSX/

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(data.query.results.json.html);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6gDMX/3/

Hope this will helps you.